# Type safe program uniform manipulation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c++11, template, opengl, type-safety

I've made an attempt at writing class wrappers around basic OpenGL objects to make managing them easier and more intuitive. Writing a generic one for program uniforms proved to require a little bit more effort than the other objects, due to there being different OpenGL functions for manipulating uniforms of different types. So, I came upon this solution, using templates and inheritance:

```
/*
    An attempt at type-safe OpenGL shader uniform manipulation

    _UniformBase forms the base class that the implementation for each data type derives from
*/
template <class T>
class _UniformBase
{
protected:
    // Each program-uniform pair is stored in a forward_list
    std::forward_list<std::pair<GLuint,GLint>> Uniforms;

    virtual void SetUniform(const T&, const GLint&) const = 0;      // Must be implemented in child classes
    virtual void SetUniform_DSA(const T&, const GLuint&, const GLint&) const = 0;

public:
    // I don't see the necessity of a copy constructor with the way that I use this class
    _UniformBase() {}
    virtual ~_UniformBase() {}

    // Gets a handle to the OpenGL uniform, given the program and the uniform name
    int Register(_Program Program_in, const char *Name_in)
    {
        GLint Location;
        GLuint Program = Program_in.GetHandle();
        if((Location = glGetUniformLocation(Program, Name_in)) == -1) return 1;
        Uniforms.push_front(std::pair<GLuint, GLint>(Program, Location));
        return 0;
    }

    // Clears out the uniform handle list...haven't used it at all
    void ClearUniforms()
    {
        Uniforms.clear();
    }

    // Sets all stored uniforms to Data_in
    void SetData(const T &Data_in)
    {
        // Can use GL_EXT_direct_state_access extension or plain OpenGL
        // Guess which one I like better
        #ifdef DIRECT_STATE_ACCESS
            for(auto &i : Uniforms)
            {
                SetUniform_DSA(Data_in, i.first, i.second);
            }
        #else
            Data = Data_in;
            GLuint Initial;
            glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, (GLint*)(&Initial));
            GLuint Previous = Initial;
            for(auto &i : Uniforms)
            {
                if(i.first != Previous)
                {
                    glUseProgram(i.first);
                    Previous = i.first;
                }
                SetUniform(&Data_in, i.second);
            }
            if(Initial != Previous) glUseProgram(Initial);
        #endif
    }

};

/*
    Just a "dummy" class that allows me to make the specializations for each datatype.

    Attempting to instantiate an unimplemented datatype will result in a compile-time error
    due to SetUniform and SetUniform_DSA being pure virtual
    (which is what I want)
*/
template <class T>
class _Uniform : public _UniformBase<T>
{

};

/*
    Here are the implementations of the SetUniform and SetUniform_DSA methods

    Each uses an OpenGL function to set the program uniform
*/
template <>
class _Uniform<glm::mat4> : public _UniformBase<glm::mat4>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const glm::mat4& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(Uniform_in, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::mat4& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniformMatrix4fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _Uniform<glm::vec4> : public _UniformBase<glm::vec4>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const glm::vec4& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec4& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform4fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _Uniform<glm::vec3> : public _UniformBase<glm::vec3>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const glm::vec3& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec3& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform3fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _Uniform<glm::vec2> : public _UniformBase<glm::vec2>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const glm::vec2& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec2& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform2fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _Uniform<float> : public _UniformBase<float>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const float& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform1fv(Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const float& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform1fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
};

template <>
class _Uniform<int> : public _UniformBase<int>
{
protected:
    void SetUniform(const int& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform1iv(Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
    void SetUniform_DSA(const int& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform1ivEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
};
```

This allows me to use a pretty simple interface for manipulating these:

```
_Uniform<glm::vec4> Test;
Test.Register(TheProgram, "SomeVec4");
Test.SetData(glm::vec4(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
```

maintaining a degree of type safety.

I like the interface as it stands, as it does what I want it to do. However, I am looking for suggestions for improvement in the implementation, as it is kinda messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across your question, and since you never got any replies from other users, I'll give you a few comments:

The first thing that bothers me with your code is the naming you've chosen. Why appending every class name with `_`? Did you know that a name beginning with an underscore and an uppercase letter is reserved in **any scope** for use by the C++ implementation? Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797) for a full discussion.

---

Empty constructors/virtual destructor:

```
_UniformBase() {}
virtual ~_UniformBase() {}
```

Can be defaulted in C++11, which is now preferred:

```
_UniformBase() = default;
virtual ~_UniformBase() = default;
```

But I don't think you need to define a default constructor at all. Don't declared it if it is not needed.

---

The logic of the return value of `_Uniform::Register()` is the opposite of what most people would expect. It return 0 on success and 1 on error. This is not a good idea, as most programmers would call it like this: `if (unif.Register( ... ))`, thinking it returns a bool, and then wonder why it always fails. It should return a `bool` and `true` on success, `false` on failure.

---

You might want to run some tests an profiling and see if there isn't a gain in switching to an `std::vector` instead of an `std::forward_list` for storage. The forward list will incur a lot of memory allocations, plus data will be scattered through the memory. Lists make very good containers when you need to insert and remove frequently from arbitrary positions. For a storage that changes *infrequently*, a `vector` is usually better. In a shader program/uniform-var list, you only set up the set of variables once, when the the program is created, so I'm almost certain a vector would be better in this case.

Comment: This was unexpected! Thanks for your input, makes me want to get back into OpenGL programming. You're right about all that, I made really odd decisions for some reason. But, I definitely wasn't aware of the underscore-followed-by-capital rule, only the double-underscore rule; good to know.

Comment: @mebob - Glad I could help `;)`

Answer (score 3):

I decided to invert the class scheme: instead of having a `_UniformBase` class and having each specialization derive from it, I now have a single `_Uniform` class which owns a copy of a `_UniformHandler` class that provides the specialized uniform-setting functions. This way, I have static polymorphism without too much complication, and with the same external interface.

```
template <class T>
class _UniformHandler;

template<>
class _UniformHandler<glm::mat4>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const glm::mat4& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(Uniform_in, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::mat4& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniformMatrix4fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};
template <>
class _UniformHandler<glm::vec4>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const glm::vec4& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec4& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform4fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _UniformHandler<glm::vec3>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const glm::vec3& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec3& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform3fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _UniformHandler<glm::vec2>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const glm::vec2& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const glm::vec2& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform2fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, glm::value_ptr(Data));
    }
};

template <>
class _UniformHandler<float>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const float& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform1fv(Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const float& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform1fvEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
};

template <>
class _UniformHandler<int>
{
public:
    inline void SetUniform(const int& Data, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glUniform1iv(Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
    inline void SetUniform_DSA(const int& Data, const GLuint &Program_in, const GLint &Uniform_in) const
    {
        glProgramUniform1ivEXT(Program_in, Uniform_in, 1, &Data);
    }
};

template <class T>
class _Uniform
{
protected:
    // Each program-uniform pair is stored in a forward_list
    std::forward_list<std::pair<GLuint,GLint>> Uniforms;
    _UniformHandler<T> UniformHandler;

public:
    _Uniform() {}
    _Uniform(const _Uniform& cp): Uniforms(cp.Uniforms) {}
    _Uniform(_Uniform&& mv): Uniforms(std::move(mv.Uniforms)) {}
    _Uniform& operator=(const _Uniform& cp)
    {
        Uniforms = cp.Uniforms;
        return *this;
    }
    _Uniform& operator=(_Uniform&& mv)
    {
        std::swap(Uniforms, mv.Uniforms);
        return *this;
    }
    ~_Uniform() {}

    // Gets a handle to the OpenGL uniform, given the program and the uniform name
    int Register(_Program Program_in, const char *Name_in)
    {
        GLint Location;
        GLuint Program = Program_in.GetHandle();
        if((Location = glGetUniformLocation(Program, Name_in)) == -1) return 1;
        Uniforms.push_front(std::pair<GLuint, GLint>(Program, Location));
        return 0;
    }

    // Clears out the uniform handle list...haven't used it at all
    void ClearUniforms()
    {
        Uniforms.clear();
    }

    // Sets all stored uniforms to Data_in
    void SetData(const T &Data_in)
    {
        // Can use GL_EXT_direct_state_access extension or plain OpenGL
        // Guess which one I like better
        #ifdef DIRECT_STATE_ACCESS
            for(auto &i : Uniforms)
            {
                UniformHandler.SetUniform_DSA(Data_in, i.first, i.second);
            }
        #else
            Data = Data_in;
            GLuint Initial;
            glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, (GLint*)(&Initial));
            GLuint Previous = Initial;
            for(auto &i : Uniforms)
            {
                if(i.first != Previous)
                {
                    glUseProgram(i.first);
                    Previous = i.first;
                }
                UniformHandler.SetUniform(&Data_in, i.second);
            }
            if(Initial != Previous) glUseProgram(Initial);
        #endif
    }

};
```